# Visibility of class variables in parent class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, visibility, getter-setter

I have a class Player.java which extends Entity.java. In entity I define the x and y coordinates. In Game.java I create a player object: `Player player = new Player(0, 0);`. What should the visibility of the x and y variables in Entity.java be? I do not want to be able to set them directly in Game.java, but if I make them private I cannot access them from the child class Player.java. Should I just make the getters and setters in Entity.java and when I need x and y in the Player.java class call those methods? That would mean that every time I need x and y in Player.java to calculate something I would need to call the getter and setter.

Main.java

```
Player player = new Player(0,0);
```

Player.java

```
public Player(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
}
```

Entity.java

```
private/public int x;
private/public int y;

public Entity(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Comment: You could just make them `protected`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want responsibility in your `Entity` class, make the properties private. Make `protected` getters and setters. This way `Player` can access the x and y properties indirectly and `Game` class can't set access these properties, because of the `protected` getters and setters.

Comment: protected show variable to all children elements and is invisible to all outside elements

Comment: Maybe I undertand the question incorrectly, but I think that's the wanted behavior in this case 'I do not want to be able to set them directly in Game.java'.

Comment: Im not sure if player is child of Entity, Game is child of Entity, both or none, thats not clear after another read :) so maybe we understand right

Answer (score 1):

You can set both `protected` and just use `super.x ; super.y ;` from the son class to access. 
the best would be to not to use setters and getters (Object programming)